# Android Programmatically created Button Persistence

Tags: android, button, persistence

So in an app I'm messing around with I programmatically create some buttons. Then I setContentView(); to a different page. Then if I come back to the original page (on which I placed the programmatically created buttons), they no longer exist. I guess this makes sense as I am calling setContentView(R.layout.main); again which is just the original xml file with no data pointing to the buttons. So is there a way to have the buttons persist over such screen transitions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use separate activities for each page? You'll get back stack behavior and preservation of activity state automatically.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that was a possibility. So I could just have my main activity programmatically start a second activity then? That should work pretty well because the second page is for the user to specify some input, therein I could just end the activity when the user was done and if the user starts the second activity again then all my input views would be be clean I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use

.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

in your Intent when you are starting the Activity which contains the Buttons.

I think this will solve your problem